# Ember Array observer not working

Tags: javascript, ember.js, observers

```
export default Ember.Object.extend({
    myArray: Ember.A([null,null,null]),
    someFunction: function () {
         console.log('i am triggered');
         myArray[1] = 3;
    }.on('init'),
    hasValue: Ember.observer('myArray.[]', function () {
         console.log('i am changed');
    })
})
```

What is the mistake here? The observer function never gets triggered though `someFunction` is always reached.

Answer (score 3):

Use [MutableArray#replace](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.MutableArray.html#method_replace):

```
 this.get('myArray').replace(1, 1, [3]);
```

This means: starting at index 1, replace 1 element, with a 3. This triggers all the necessary dependencies and observers defined as `myArray.[]`.

I'm surprised that your code does not spit out a ReferenceError, since you are referring to an undeclared variable `myArray` inside `someFunction`.

There's a convenience function for this that I can't put my finger on at the moment. Also, be aware that observers may not fire during initialization.

Comment: Isn't there a defined ember way to add an observer to primitive array object other than this tweak?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, no. It you simply change an array element directly, Ember has no way to detect that or respond to it. It only knows how to fire all its observers and dependent properties when you use the APIs that allow it do so. At some point far in the future, with `Object.observe` implemented everywhere and Ember supporting it, this could and will change. As things stand, we are stuck in `this.get('foo')` and `notifyPropertyChange` and `addObject` land for several more years at least.

Comment: Is it the same case for Ember.A([1,2,3,4]) as well? Not the native array,  but an Ember array?

Comment: Actually, `Ember.A([1,2,3,4])` and `[1,2,3,4]` are for all practical purposes the same, because Ember places its methods on the JS `Array` object (unless you explicitly tell it not to).

Answer (score 2):

Using `myArray.[]` will only notify you when items are added or removed from the array. The correct way to do this is to use `myArray.@each.key` which will observe all changes on the `key` property for each item in the array.

If I'm being honest, I actually don't know how to observe an array of primitives for changes (except for added/removed changes), so would probably do something like:

```
myArray: Ember.A([Ember.Object.create(), Ember.Object.create(), Ember.Object.create()]);

myArray[1].set('id', 3);
```

And then observe `myArray.@each.id`. If you want to project those ids you could use `mapBy`:

```
ids: Ember.computed.mapBy('myArray', 'id')
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: aaah....thats no longer an array.
First we go away from array to Ember.A() and then inside that we create more ember objects!

Comment: I don't think you need to use `Ember.Array`, but you (probably) need to use ember objects if you want to observe changes on the items.

Comment: Sometimes entire code is not in one person control :)  
I am forced to use arrays for various reasons.

Comment: If you have a way of knowing when the data changed elsewhere (e.g. jquery event, web socket, ajax call etc...) then you can always manually invalidate the array and it will get rebound. with ember 1.13+ that should still be plenty fast.